# Instagram basic display api alternative image size

Tags: instagram-api

Is it possible to get alternative image sizes using instagram basic display api? So far I haven't found any possibilities on [api doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/media), but when I inspected instagram web app html source I found `srcset` attribute which contains several images for different versions, so they exist. Is it possible to get it using the api somehow?

Comment: Reached same problem. Knowing image size metadata from an API is pretty basic as every interface needs this. There is also no way to load a thumbnail/resized version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible with the new API :((((((

Comment: I am astonished by this... I mean, what's the point to get a IG feed for a website widget if the images are huge as a screen each...